# How to demonstrate a vector norm identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I'm trying to demonstrate the following identity:

$\| y-x \|^{2}= \|\frac{1}{2}(x+y) \, \|^{2}- \|\frac{1}{2}(x-y) \, \|^{2}+i\|\frac{1}{2}(x+iy) \, \|^{2}- i||\frac{1}{2}(x-iy) \, \|^2$

I've tried a lot of times but always something's wrong.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Provide more context please: where are living $x$ and $y$? and is it a special norm?

Answer (score 0):

For $x,y$ in a [complex Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Definition) $(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ we have

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\langle v,w \rangle &=&\frac{1}{4}\left[2\langle v,w \rangle + 2\langle w,v \rangle\right]+\frac{i}{4}\left[-2i \langle v,w \rangle+2i\langle w,v \rangle\right]\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\left[\langle v+w,v+w \rangle-
\langle v-w,v-w \rangle\right]\\ &&+\frac{i}{4}\left[\langle v+iw,v+iw \rangle-\langle v-iw,v-iw \rangle\right]\\
&=& \|\frac{1}{2}(v+w)\|^2-\|\frac{1}{2}(v-w)\|^2+i\|\frac{1}{2}(v+iw)\|^2-i\|\frac{1}{2}(v-iw)\|^2
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thus I have doubts about the equality in the OP (take any $x \neq 0$, then we would have $0>-\|x\|^2=\|x\|^2>0$)